# C# - Remove Event From Browser

Tags: c#, delegates

I add an event to `webBrowser` as below code:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => {};
```

Now How can I remove this event inside of it? Somthing like this:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => {
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= this;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a reference to your delegate. Something like this:

```
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler complete = null;
complete = (s, e) => {
    webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= complete;
};
webBrowser.DocumentComplete += complete;
```

Comment: Thanks... There is No solution without referencing?

Comment: @K2evil not to my knowledge.

Comment: @K2evil - Yes, there is - more or less. I'll post an answer to show you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this answer in as an adjunct to the accepted answer.

It is possible to do some delegate magic to avoid explicitly taking a reference for detaching a handler.

Here's the final code that can be written (in your `webBrowser` case):

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Disposable
        .HandleOnce(
            h => webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += h,
            h => webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= h,
            (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted!");
            });
```

Keeping a reference to `subscription` is optional, but calling `subscription.Dispose()` allows the handler to be cancelled before it runs once.

To start with you need this code:

```
public static class Disposable
{
    public static IDisposable Create(Action dispose)
    {
        if (dispose == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dispose");
        return (IDisposable)new AnonymousDisposable(dispose);
    }

    private sealed class AnonymousDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        private volatile Action _dispose;

        public AnonymousDisposable(Action dispose)
        {
            _dispose = dispose;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Action action = Interlocked.Exchange<Action>(ref _dispose, (Action)null);
            if (action != null)
            {
                action();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows any action to be turned into a `IDisposable` that will call the action once and only once when `.Dispose()` is called.

So, this code:

```
var subscription = Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Done."));
subscription.Dispose();
subscription.Dispose();
```

...causes `Done.` to be printed on the console only once.

Now, the `HandleOnce` method can be added to the `Disposable` class:

```
public static IDisposable HandleOnce(
    Action<WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler> addHandler,
    Action<WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler> removeHandler,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler)
{
    if (addHandler == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("addHandler");
    if (removeHandler == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("removeHandler");
    if (handler == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler nested = null;
    nested = (s, e) =>
    {
        removeHandler(nested);
        handler(s, e);
    };
    addHandler(nested);
    return Disposable.Create(() => removeHandler(nested));
}
```

Now, it is possible to make completely generic version of this code that doesn't have to be coded to know about delegates like `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`. Here it is:

```
public static class Disposable
{
    public static IDisposable Create(Action dispose)
    {
        if (dispose == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dispose");
        return (IDisposable)new AnonymousDisposable(dispose);
    }

    public static IDisposable Handle<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
        Action<TDelegate> addHandler,
        Action<TDelegate> removeHandler,
        TDelegate handler)
    {
        if (addHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("addHandler");
        if (removeHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("removeHandler");
        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

        addHandler(handler);

        return Disposable.Create(() => removeHandler(handler));
    }

    public static IDisposable HandleOnce<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
        Action<TDelegate> addHandler,
        Action<TDelegate> removeHandler,
        TDelegate handler)
    {
        if (addHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("addHandler");
        if (removeHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("removeHandler");
        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

        Action<object, TEventArgs> inner =
            CreateDelegate<Action<object, TEventArgs>>(
                handler,
                typeof(TDelegate).GetMethod("Invoke"));

        TDelegate outer = default(TDelegate);

        IDisposable detach = Disposable.Create(() => removeHandler(outer));

        Action<object, TEventArgs> nested = (s, e) =>
        {
            removeHandler(outer);
            inner(s, e);
        };

        outer = CreateDelegate<TDelegate>(
            nested,
            typeof(Action<object, TEventArgs>).GetMethod("Invoke"));

        addHandler(outer);

        return detach;
    }

    public static TDelegate CreateDelegate<TDelegate>(object o, MethodInfo method)
    {
        return (TDelegate)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate), o, method);
    }

    public static IDisposable Handle(
        Action<EventHandler> addHandler,
        Action<EventHandler> removeHandler,
        EventHandler handler)
    {
        return Disposable.Handle<EventHandler, EventArgs>(addHandler, removeHandler, handler);
    }

    public static IDisposable HandleOnce(
        Action<EventHandler> addHandler,
        Action<EventHandler> removeHandler,
        EventHandler handler)
    {
        if (addHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("addHandler");
        if (removeHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("removeHandler");
        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

        EventHandler nested = null;
        IDisposable detach = Disposable.Create(() => removeHandler(nested));
        nested = (s, e) =>
        {
            detach.Dispose();
            handler(s, e);
        };
        addHandler(nested);
        return detach;
    }

    private sealed class AnonymousDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        private volatile Action _dispose;

        public AnonymousDisposable(Action dispose)
        {
            _dispose = dispose;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Action action = Interlocked.Exchange<Action>(ref _dispose, (Action)null);
            if (action != null)
            {
                action();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above class also contains code for handling multiple event occurrences, not just `HandleOnce`.

Now the code to call this looks like this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Disposable
        .HandleOnce<
                WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler,
                WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs>(
            h => webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += h,
            h => webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= h,
            (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted!");
            });
```

Again there's no need to keep the reference to `subscription` unless you want to detach before the `DocumentCompleted` event fires.

Comment: It's such a great informative answer... But is hard to implement... Thank you for share your information with me

Comment: @K2evil - Thanks, but why do you say it is hard to implement? I've provided all of the code.

Comment: I mean if I reference handler, It add only 2 line to my code... But your solution needs tons of new line :D I will use your codes when there is no way to reference Handler

Comment: @K2evil - That's the point of creating libraries. You should see how many lines are in the .NET Framework. Granted my code is fairly complicated, but it means you only have to write a single line of code when you want to use it.

Comment: Correct... It seems that you are professional in c#. I have a strange issue that couldn't solve it with my knowledge... Can you please see this post and help me if you know about this problem: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119590/application-run-cause-to-hang-program)

Comment: @K2evil - I've put a comment on your other question.